# I wanted to add a annotation point in my project using swift. But I does not add on my simulator

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am adding the annotation whenever the location gets updated but it does not work for simulator.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    print("my Current location is \(location?.coordinate.latitude) ")
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let myCurrentLocation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myCurrentLocation.coordinate=center
    myCurrentLocation.title = "Where I am"
    myCurrentLocation.subtitle = "Here I am"

    self.mapView .addAnnotation(myCurrentLocation)
}
```

Comment: Did you turn on the location updates for the simulator?

Comment: Did you adopt MKMapViewDelegate Protocol and implement `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` delegate method?

Comment: Yes I had adopted.

Comment: Yes i have turned ON and updated my info.plist but does not work yet !